# Deleting an unwanted character in a string

Tags: ruby, string, csv, encoding

I am parsing a CSV file and converting each element in UTF-8 :

```
CSV.foreach(@data_source, { :col_sep => ';' , quote_char: "\x00", :encoding => "CP850"}) do |row|
    row.map! {|x| x.force_encoding('UTF-8') unless x.nil? ; x.scrub!("") unless x.nil? ; x.delete('\u2FEC') unless x.nil? }
end
```

The script then does a bunch of calculations and then saves the data in `xlsx` format using `axlsx` gem.

I added `x.delete('\u2FEC') unless x.nil?` because I found that in the source file, there was this strange sequence that later causes and "Unreadable content" error in Excel.

I found that it solves the "Unreadable content" issue **but** it not only deletes the `"\u2FEC"` sequence, it deletes every occurence of the character `"2"` too.

Do you have any idea how I can get rid of **only** `"\u2FEC"` and not of every `"2"` in my rows ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you writing `'\u2FEC'` with `delete`, and at the same time writing `"\u2FEC"` in other parts of this question? Your problem stems from such sloppiness.

Answer (score 3):

Single-quoted strings don't support Unicode escapes. (In fact, they don't support *any* escapes other than `\'` and `\\`.)

You need to use either a double-quoted string or enter the character directly into the single-quoted string instead of a Unicode escape sequence.